# Prevent Material-UI Dialog from applying inline styles to body

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In the image below, you can see `padding-right` and `overflow` inline styles that have been added to the `<body>` element when the Dialog was opened.

[image]

How can I prevent Material-UI from adding those styles to the body element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This functionality is part of `Modal` (used by `Dialog`) and is implemented [here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.9.14/packages/material-ui/src/Modal/ModalManager.js#L61).

You can turn this off by adding the `disableScrollLock` prop to your `Dialog`.

Example:

```
<Dialog
      disableScrollLock
      onClose={handleClose}
      aria-labelledby="simple-dialog-title"
      open={open}
    >
  ...
</Dialog>
```

[image: Edit Material demo]

Documentation: https://material-ui.com/api/modal/#props